# Silverlight - Accessing Microsoft MapPoint Web Service

Tags: silverlight, mappoint

I need to access the Microsoft MapPoint Web Service (not the Bing Maps Web Service) from a Silverlight application. When I attempt to access the web service, it prompts me for my username / password. I enter my username and password and then a message box pops up that says "not found".

My question is, how do I access the MapPoint Web Service from a Silverlight application?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you should buy subscription in order to access MapPoint services...